# WiFi adaper not found on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, hp, modprobe

I cannot connect via WiFi and I've tried following the instructions in another question, but I get an error when `modprobe`ing the module `rtl8273de`.

You can see the commands I ran on a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KF8WSC5gzB/).

The error is as follows:

> No wifi adapter found

I tried `modprobe`ing, but I got the below error:

```
georgeorwell@georgeorwell:~/rtlwifi_new$ sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723de not found.
```

I'm using an *HP bs15-000xx laptop*, and the WiFi was working (albeit rather slowly) before, when I had windows 10 installed.

I'd be happy to paste a config output somewhere...

Comment: Thanks Pomsky, I've edited with a paste of all the commands I ran.

Comment: Hi Kulfy - I followed that until the end, then got the following error:

could not insert 'rtl8723be': Required key not available

Comment: From the paste bin output I can see that the module was not built. You can't install without building. You need to go back to the "make install" command and make sure it builds without errors.

Comment: @m137o Kulfy mistakenly suggested a wrong duplicate, that question is about rtl8723**b**e whereas you have rtl8723**d**e.

Comment: Thanks, that worked in getting the WiFi up and running, but my signal is extremely weak (even after changing the selected antenna using 
$ sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf <<< "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2")

I have 400Mbps with my cable connected, but nothing more than 12Mbps when using WiFi.

Comment: Try ant_sel=1. Higher number doesn't guarantee greater signal strength.